# Why does removing return give me an error: expected type `()` but found type

Tags: rust

I'm writing an `is_prime` function in Rust, and I was under the impression that simply writing `true` was the equivalent of `return true;`, but this is not the case in my function:

```
fn is_prime(number: i64) -> bool {
    for i in 2i64..number {
        if number % i == 0 && i != number {
            false
        }
    }
    true
}
```

This will give me the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:13
  |
4 |             false
  |             ^^^^^ expected (), found bool
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `bool`
```

Replacing `true` and `false` with `return true;` / `return false;` works, but why does using the previous not compile?

Comment: Btw, the `i != number` check is pointless, since `range` doesn't include the second endpoint (i.e. it acts like Python). Also, the funciton can be written as ` fn is_prime(number: i64) -> bool { !range(2, number).any(|i| number % i == 0) }`.

Comment: @dbaupp: I’d write `fn is_prime(number: i64) -> bool { range(2, number).all(|i| number % i != 0) }` instead.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan you say "all not", I say "not any", de morgan says "who cares" :P (Also, weird that my original code isn't code formatted: `fn is_prime(number: i64) -> bool { !range(2, number).any(|i| number % i == 0) }`.)

Comment: @dbaupp Yeah, but I’m de only Morgan around here. 

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rust is expression-oriented. In any block, the last expression inside it is the value of the block. Thus, for a function, the last value in the block is treated as a return value.

In other blocks, though, this is not the case—the last value is, after all, treated as the value of the block, not as a return value for the function.

Take the snippet in isolation with just a bit added for clarity:

```
let has_factor = if number % i == 0 && i != number {
    false
}
```

This means that the outcome of the `if` statement as a whole is `false` if the clause is true, and that value is then duly inserted into the `has_factor` variable. If the clause is *not* true, then the `else` clause will be evaluated. Given that there is no else clause, it is as though `else { }` had been written, which is equivalent to `else { () }`. This else block evaluates to `()`, the unit type. Now we have a mismatch: is the `if` block (and hence the `has_factor` variable) of the type `bool`, as the `if` block requires, or `()`, as the [lack of] else block requires? This is where the error comes from.

**Summary:** you can’t just omit the `return` keyword, because that’s not what the expression orientation means. At the end of a *function*, they boil down to the same thing and the sans-`return` form should be preferred, but in other locations they are not equivalent and `return` must be explicit.

**Final code:**

```
fn is_prime(number: i64) -> bool {
    for i in 2..number {
        if number % i == 0 && i != number {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}
```

Comment: Also, note that the value of a for/while/loop expression is always `()`.

Comment: @FrancisGagné This might be a change that happened since you commented, but `loop` expressions can have arbitrary return values by using the `break` expression (all `break`s from a particular `loop` have to have matching return types, of course). This only applies to `loop` er... loops, specifically. `for` and `while` are still always `()` - `break`s from those kinds of loops won't accept a value.

Comment: @8bittree Right, `break`ing out of a `loop` with a value was added in [Rust 1.19.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1190-2017-07-20). When I wrote my earlier comment, [Rust 0.11.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-0110-2014-07-02) had just been released! :)