# What does "mismatched types: expected `()`" mean when using an if expression?

Tags: rust

I tried to implement fizzbuzz in Rust and failed with some arcane error:

```
fn main() {
    let mut i = 1;

    while i < 100 {
        println!(
            "{}{}{}",
            if i % 3 == 0 { "Fizz" },
            if i % 5 == 0 { "Buzz" },
            if !(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) { i },
        );
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `()` but found `&'static str` (expected () but found &-ptr)
                 if i % 3 == 0 { "Fizz" },
                               ^~~~~~~~~~
error: mismatched types: expected `()` but found `&'static str` (expected () but found &-ptr)
                 if i % 5 == 0 { "Buzz" },
                               ^~~~~~~~~~
error: mismatched types: expected `()` but found `<generic integer #0>` (expected () but found integral variable)
                 if !(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
                     i
                 });
```

Newer versions of Rust have a slightly modified error message:

```
error[E0317]: if may be missing an else clause
 --> src/main.rs:7:13
  |
7 |             if i % 3 == 0 { "Fizz" },
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found &str
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `&str`

error[E0317]: if may be missing an else clause
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |             if i % 5 == 0 { "Buzz" },
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found &str
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `&str`

error[E0317]: if may be missing an else clause
 --> src/main.rs:9:13
  |
9 |             if !(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) { i },
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `{integer}`
```

I found [why does removing return give me an error: expected '()' but found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502282/why-does-removing-return-give-me-an-error-expected-but-found), but adding `return` as suggested didn't help.

What do these errors mean and how do I avoid them in the future?

Comment: Btw, you should use `for i in range(1, 100) { ... }` rather than `while` + manual incrementing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `if i % 3 == 0 { "Fizz" }` returns either unit `()` or `&'static str`.  Change the if expressions to return the same type in both cases, for example by adding a `else { "" }`.

Comment: Then I have a problem with the last one - if I do `i.to_str()` to make them the same type I get `error: if and else have incompatible types: expected \`collections::string::String\` but found \`&'static str\` (expected struct collections::string::String but found &-ptr)`

Comment: `"".to_str()` for matching types on the last case. By the way, a more idiomatic fizzbuzz would use match and a println! for each match arm. See if you can refactor your code after you get your current attempt working.

Comment: What's the difference between the string returned by `to_str` and a plain `""`, is one of them boxed?