# expected enum `std::result::Result`, found ()

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust.
I try to create a `Point` struct that implements `Eq` and `Debug`, so I did this:

```rust
use std::fmt;

pub struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Point {
        Point{
            x: x,
            y: y,
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Debug for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "({}, {})", self.x, self.y);
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Point {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        return self.x == other.x && self.y == other.y;
    }
}

impl Eq for Point { }
```

Whenever I try to compile the program, I get an error on this line: `fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {`, saying:

```
mismatched types

expected enum `std::result::Result`, found ()

note: expected type `std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error>`
         found type `()`rustc(E0308)
```

From what I understand, `()` is like the `void` type, and when you wrap it around `Result` like this: `Result<(), Error>`, you basically expect the `void` type but you also catch errors. Is it right? In that case, why do I get a compilation error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does removing return give me an error: expected type \`()\` but found type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502282/why-does-removing-return-give-me-an-error-expected-type-but-found-type)

Comment: @Stargateur It's kinda similar.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your semicolon `;` turns that line into an [expression statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/statements.html#expression-statements), preventing the Result from being returned from the function. This is covered in The Rust Programming Language [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html#function-bodies-contain-statements-and-expressions):

> Expressions do not include ending semicolons. If you add a semicolon to the end of an expression, you turn it into a statement, which will then not return a value.

When I copy your code into https://play.rust-lang.org, I get:

```
   |
18 |     fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
   |        ---                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found `()`
   |        |
   |        implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
19 |         write!(f, "({}, {})", self.x, self.y);
   |                                              - help: consider removing this semicolon
   |
   = note:   expected enum `std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error>`
           found unit type `()`
```

If you remove the semicolon, it works. (You could also have chosen to add an explicit `return` instead.)

Comment: Cool! it works now. It follows that I was wrong with this assumption: `when you wrap it around Result like this: Result<(), Error>, you basically expect the void type but you also catch errors` you still have to return (explicitly or implicitly) when your function expects to return a `Result<(), something>`

Comment: It's true that `Result<(), Error>` is similar to `()` but it might also be an error. I think that's separate from the issue of whether your function is correctly returning a value or not